# Laravel command - Only optional argument

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I have a command with this signature

```
order:check {--order}
```

And execute this:

```
php artisan order:check --order 7
```

For some reason that results in this exception

```
  [RuntimeException]                                 
  Too many arguments, expected arguments "command".
```

Why? I want that this command can either be executed as `php artisan order:check` or with an optional order id `php artisan order:check --order X`

Comment: Try `--order=X`. It may be parsing the 7 as a separate argument instead of an option value.

Comment: @aynber still he needs to add the equal sign to the definition of the command like Cy pointed out

Comment: @Michael read the section : **Options With Values** https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The `{--order}` option (without an `=` sign) declares a *switch* option, which takes *no arguments*. If the switch option is present, its value equals `true`, and, when absent, `false` (`--help` is like a switch—no argument needed).

When we provide an argument on the command line for this option, the console framework cannot match the input to an option with an argument, so it throws the error as shown in the question.

To allow the option to accept an argument, change the command's `$signature` to:

```
protected $signature = 'order:check {--order=}'
```

Note the addition of the equal sign after `--order`. This tells the framework that the `--order` option *requires* an argument—the command will throw an exception if the user doesn't provide one.

If we want our command to accept an option *with or without* an argument, we can use a similar syntax to provide a default value:

```
protected $signature = 'order:check {--order=7}'
```

...but this doesn't seem useful for this particular case.

After we set this up, we can call the command, passing an argument for `--order`. The framework supports both formats:

```
$ php artisan order:check --order=7 
$ php artisan order:check --order 7
```

...and then use the value of `order` in our command:

```
$orderNumber = $this->option('order');  // 7
```

Comment: In this case I think he should use the folllowing command `php artisan order:check --order=7` to execute it

Comment: @teeyo you describe the "official" syntax, but the command parser supports both common argument formats. `--order 7` will also work in most cases.

Comment: Actually, on Laravel 6 if you describe an option like this `{--foo=}` and you don't provide it when you run the command, its value is `null`.

Answer (score 9):

The above answers are correct but still trying to add some extra points. Hope below things helps

**Mandatory Arguments**

```
protected $signature = 'order:check {param}';
```

**Optional Arguments**

```
protected $signature = 'order:check {param?}';
```

**Optional Arguments with default values**

```
protected $signature = 'order:check {param=foo}';
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan